# Will Google cloud charge me for their text-to-speech API if I stay below the 1 million character per month threshold?

Tags: api, google-cloud

I registered google cloud account and want to use Text-To-Speech API on my own server with [github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php](http://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) library.

On API page in block "Pricing" written that using less than 1 millon chracters/month is free. But lower is a note "Additional charges may also apply from infrastructure you use to call the API"

Question: This note applies to users google cloud VPS, right? If I will use API how I described (send requests from my own server) first million of characters will be absolutely free? Google wont take a cent?